# Page number intersects text when using fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

As i mentioned in title, i can't manage fancyhdr to work. I can't remove page numbers. And page numbering is not stable. And this is the result. As you can see one iii is at the bottom but iv is at the heading and intersecting with text.[image: undesired result]

Sorry for bad english.

This is mwe(i think) Because of the document is too long i did not dump the all code. But i can if it is needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\addto\extrasturkish{\uccode`i=\string"9D \lccode`I=\string"19 }
\addto\noextrasturkish{\uccode`i=`I \lccode`I=`i }


\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0 pt}


\raggedbottom
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\counterwithin{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\counterwithin{subparagraph}{paragraph}
\makeatother


%\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
%\epstopdfsetup{update}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.ps}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing{\section}
    {0pt}
    {-12 pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
    {-10 pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
    {0pt}   
    {-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
    {-10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\titlespacing{\subsubsection}
    {0pt}
    {-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
    {-10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\titlespacing\paragraph
    {0pt}
    {-12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
    {-10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase}
    {\thesection.}
    {1em}
    {} 

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection.}
    {1em}
    {}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}
    {\thesubsubsection.}
    {1em }
    {}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\itshape\normalsize}
    {\theparagraph.}
    {1em}
    {}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{ 0 cm} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
%\raggedbottom
\setitemize{topsep=-12pt}
\setenumerate{topsep=-12pt}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\alph*.}
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\newpage\stdsection}

\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{=}

(...)

(...)

\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.245\baselineskip}

\tableofcontents
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\end{spacing}

(...)

(...)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your problem may lie with the combination of `nohead,nofoot` via [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) in conjunction with requiring a header/footer via [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

Comment: wow thanks. But one page number is at the top one is the bottom this time

Comment: This is because of the page styles set by your document class (and possibly packages loaded in the preamble).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do not use any margin setting *after* loading `fancyhdr`. Delete your

```
\setlength{\headheight}{ 0 cm}
```

and use `geometry` for any setting. To get the same behaviour on the first page for chapters redefine the pagestyle:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \chead{{\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

Comment: good answer but it still keeps one number at bottom one number at top

Comment: sure, that is the default. If you do not want that, then redefine `\fancypagestyle{plain}{ ...settings ...}`. See documentation on page 7/8.

Comment: see my edited answer